# Add new smarty template to an existing page

Tags: extension, hooks, civix

I want to add a new template part to the activity edit & view page, I have been trying number of hooks to do it but could not figure out which one best to use.

[image]

I am trying to do something similar to what is explained here https://youtu.be/lrk8X_jt0wU?list=PLjSU7YfE0E00Xv9b_VqwjDjAcFUVtR8k5&t=837 but for activity edit & view pages.

```
function _myactivity_civix_civicrm_summary($contactID, $content){
CRM_Core_Region::instance('page-body')->add([
    'template' => 'templates/myactivity.tpl'
]);
}
```

Any suggestion or better approach would be great help.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: so do you want to update the activity with specific word in the description once it is completed - Right?

Comment: @ramesh - No, I am looking for correct hook or method to embed additional template files and display my extra stuff on the activity page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am assuming you want to add some stuff at the bottom of the activity page, correct?

First of all, you need to establish if you are adding to a civicrm page or form. You can do a little test with the hook buildForm (see https://docs.civicrm.org/dev/en/latest/hooks/hook_civicrm_buildForm/) and check the **formName** or with the hook pageRun (see https://docs.civicrm.org/dev/en/latest/hooks/hook_civicrm_pageRun/) and check the name of the page.

Once you have established which hook you need to use you can add the template with the CRM_Core_Region.

Comment: Thank you @erikh-civicoop, I think _hook_civicrm_buildForm_ is the right hook for me, I am testing with it. You are correct that I want to add some extra stuff at the bottom of the activity page.